# Align node name in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to align the name of a node to the top left of the rectangle.  [Left alignment in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12973/left-alignment-in-tikz) (and a few other posts) mention to alter the `text width` parameter, but this had no effect when used in the code below.

```
back group/.style={fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed, 
                   inner xsep=15pt, inner ysep=10pt, 
                   anchor=west, text width=8.8cm}
```

Also  from [TIKZ-PGF: Align two text-nodes to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66762/tikz-pgf-align-two-text-nodes-to-the-left/66768)  I tried to change the relevant bit of the code below to use `anchor` or `right` but these had no effect.

```
\node (bk1) [back group, anchor=west] [fit=(a) (b)] {Some words of some stuff};
\node (bk1) [back group, right] [fit=(a) (b)] {Some words of some stuff};
```

How can this be done please?

(ps I am trying to add a bounding box around rows of nodes and then add a label descriptor, I'd welcome if there is a better way. Thanks).

---

My code

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta,positioning,backgrounds,fit}     

\tikzset{%
  line/.style={draw, thick, color=black!50, -LaTeX},
  back group/.style={fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, 
                     dashed, inner xsep=15pt, inner ysep=10pt, 
                     anchor=west},
  block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
                  text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]    
    \node [block] (a) {a};
    \node [block, right of=a] (b) {b};
    \path [line] (a) -- (b);

 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \node (bk1) [back group] [fit=(a) (b)] {Some words of some stuff};
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`Some words of some stuff` is the name that I'd like in the top-left.

Comment: Could you please try to explain better what you want? Does ` \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \node (bk1) [back group] [fit=(a)
  (b)] {};
  \end{scope}
  \node[anchor=south west] at (bk1.north west) {Some words of some stuff};` give you what you want? Is your question how to get this from one rather than two nodes?

Comment: @marmot; thank you for your comment. That is close to what I would like, however, I would like the text within the node at the top-left (as you have done) rather than outside. So the text should be within the yellow rectangle in the top-left position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick proposal (note that I had to increase `inner ysep` a bit in order to fit the text.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta,positioning,backgrounds,fit}     

\tikzset{%
  line/.style={draw, thick, color=black!50, -LaTeX},
  back group/.style={fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, 
                     dashed, inner xsep=15pt, inner ysep=15pt, 
                     anchor=west},
  block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
                  text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]    
    \node [block] (a) {a};
    \node [block, right of=a] (b) {b};
    \path [line] (a) -- (b);

 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \node (bk1) [back group] [fit=(a)
     (b)] {};
  \end{scope}
  \node[anchor=north west] at (bk1.north west) {Some words of some stuff};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that looks great. May I ask a for a wee bit of explanation please.: the line `[anchor=north west] at (bk1.north west) `; does this create an invisible node underneath, or does it create a node in the NW of the yellow node, or?

Comment: @user20650 It just creates a node (but a label is also a node) whose north east corner is the north east corner of the yellow fit node.

Comment: I see thanks. (I added a fill colour so it would show `[anchor=north west, fill=red]`). Thanks again.